# Bootstrap Modal sitting behind backdrop when calling code behind in asp.net webforms

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, updatepanel

I've been struggling with this for the last couple of days,
I'm trying to get an editable grid view system in asp.net using the fallowing tutorial:

[Editable Grid View System using BootStrap in ASP.Net](http://www.mindstick.com/Articles/0f1b65c3-b0f6-4a93-b4b5-56c278d855c2/?Editable%20Grid%20View%20System%20using%20BootStrap%20in%20ASP%20Net)

I want to be able click "add new record" and the pop up modal should display and let me add a new record, the issue that I'm having is that whenever I clicked on "add new record" the

```
   <div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>
```

seems to be covering everything.

Here are some pictures describing the problem.

Before I clicked:

[image]

And after I clicked:

[image]

I can't seem to find what's causing this.

Please take a look at my code:

```
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head runat="server">
     <title></title>
     <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
     <script src="Script/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
      <script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
     <form id="form1" runat="server">
     <div  style="width: 90%; margin-right: 5%; margin-left: 5%; text-align: center">

             <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager1" />
             <h1>Grid View System</h1>

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upCrudGrid" runat="server">

            <ContentTemplate>

                <asp:GridView ID="grdvCrudOperation" runat="server" Width="940px" HorizontalAlign="Center"

                   AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true"

                    DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table table-hover table-striped" OnRowCommand="grdvCrudOperation_RowCommand">

                    <Columns>

                        <asp:ButtonField CommandName="detail" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-info" ButtonType="Button" Text="Detail" HeaderText="Detailed View">

                            <ControlStyle CssClass="btn btn-info"></ControlStyle>

                        </asp:ButtonField>

                        <asp:ButtonField CommandName="editRecord" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-info" ButtonType="Button" Text="Edit" HeaderText="Edit Record">

                            <ControlStyle CssClass="btn btn-info"></ControlStyle>

                        </asp:ButtonField>

                        <asp:ButtonField CommandName="deleteRecord" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-info" ButtonType="Button" Text="Delete" HeaderText="Delete Record">

                            <ControlStyle CssClass="btn btn-info"></ControlStyle>

                        </asp:ButtonField>

                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" />

                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />

                        <asp:BoundField DataField="EmailID" HeaderText="EmailID" />

                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" />

                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Contact" HeaderText="Contact NO" />

                    </Columns>

                </asp:GridView>

                <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add New Record" CssClass="btn btn-info" OnClick="btnAdd_Click"  />

            </ContentTemplate>

            <Triggers>

            </Triggers>

        </asp:UpdatePanel>

        <div id="detailModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

            <div class="modal-header">

                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>

                <h3 id="myModalLabel">Details</h3>

            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">

                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">

                    <ContentTemplate>

                        <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" CssClass="table table-bordered table-hover" BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" FieldHeaderStyle-Wrap="false" FieldHeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" FieldHeaderStyle-BackColor="LavenderBlush" FieldHeaderStyle-ForeColor="Black" BorderStyle="Groove" AutoGenerateRows="False">

                            <Fields>

                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />

                                <asp:BoundField DataField="EmailID" HeaderText="EmailID" />

                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" />

                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Contact" HeaderText="Contact NO" />

                            </Fields>

                        </asp:DetailsView>

                    </ContentTemplate>

                    <Triggers>

                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="grdvCrudOperation" EventName="RowCommand" />

                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAdd" EventName="Click" />

                    </Triggers>

                </asp:UpdatePanel>

                <div class="modal-footer">

                    <button class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="editModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

            <div class="modal-header">

                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>

                <h3 id="editModalLabel">Edit Record</h3>

            </div>

            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upEdit" runat="server">

                <ContentTemplate>

                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <asp:HiddenField ID="HfUpdateID" runat="server" />

                        <table class="table">

                            <tr>

                                <td>Name : </td>

                                <td>

                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNameUpdate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>

                                <td>

                            </tr>

                            <tr>

                                <td>EmailID</td>

                                <td>

                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmailIDUpdate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>

                            </tr>

                            <tr>

                                <td>Address</td>

                                <td>

                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddressUpdate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>

                            </tr>

                            <tr>

                                <td>Contact No</td>

                                <td>

                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtContactUpdate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>

                            </tr>

                        </table>

                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">

                        <asp:Label ID="lblResult" Visible="false" runat="server"></asp:Label>

                        <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Update" CssClass="btn btn-info" OnClick="btnSave_Click"  />

                        <button class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>

                    </div>

                </ContentTemplate>

                <Triggers>

                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="grdvCrudOperation" EventName="RowCommand" />

                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSave" EventName="Click" />

                </Triggers>

            </asp:UpdatePanel>

        </div>

        <div id="addModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

            <div id="myModalContainer">

                 <div class="modal-header">

                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>

                <h3 id="addModalLabel">Add New Record</h3>

            </div>

            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upAdd" runat="server">

                <ContentTemplate>

                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">

                            <tr>

                                <td>Name : </td>

                                <td>

                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNameAdd" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>

                            </tr>

                            <tr>

                                <td>EmailID :</td>

                                <td>

                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmailIDAdd" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>

                            </tr>

                            <tr>

                                <td>Address:</td>

                                <td>

                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddressAdd" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>

                            </tr>

                            <tr>

                                <td>Contact No:</td>

                                <td>

                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtContactAdd" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>

                            </tr>

                        </table>

                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">

                        <asp:Button ID="btnAddRecord" runat="server" Text="Add" CssClass="btn btn-info" OnClick="btnAddRecord_Click" />

                        <button class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>

                    </div>

                </ContentTemplate>

                <Triggers>

                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAddRecord" EventName="Click" />

                </Triggers>

            </asp:UpdatePanel>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="deleteModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="delModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

            <div class="modal-header">

                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>

                <h3 id="delModalLabel">Delete Record</h3>

            </div>

            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upDel" runat="server">

                <ContentTemplate>

                    <div class="modal-body">

                        Are you sure you want to delete the record?

                        <asp:HiddenField ID="HfDeleteID" runat="server" />

                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">

                        <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" CssClass="btn btn-info" OnClick="btnDelete_Click"  />

                        <button class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>

                    </div>

                </ContentTemplate>

                <Triggers>

                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnDelete" EventName="Click" />

                </Triggers>

            </asp:UpdatePanel>

        </div>
</div>
</form>
```

C# code behind:

```
   protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

        sb.Append(@"<script type='text/javascript'>");
        sb.Append("$('#addModal').modal('show');");
        sb.Append(@"</script>");

        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "AddShowModalScript", sb.ToString(), false);
   }
```

I'd really appreciate any suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: thanks for replying to this, I actually managed to solve this issue by looking at the fallowing answer: [Bootstrap Modal not working.(Asp.net, C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21167040/bootstrap-modal-not-working-asp-net-c?rq=1) Thank you so much for your suggestions, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

See: 
[Bootstrap modal appearing under background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636667/bootstrap-modal-appearing-under-background)

```
$('#myModal').appendTo("body").modal('show');
```

did the trick for me

Comment: Its helpful to add a summary of articles you link to in case those links disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I just add some CSS style to prevent this issue:

```
.modal-backdrop{
    position:relative !important;
}
```

**This method works even with nested modals.**

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing Your Trigger from :

```
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAddRecord" EventName="Click" />
```

To:

```
<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAddRecord" />
```